# Print array of a function that return a pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Hello I try do a function that can split every text I want. For example if I enter apple::google::dsf and the delimitor is :: every element will be put in a place in an array. I success to do this, but now I want to be able to use this array in my main. So I want to print the array that I return in my function in the main and not to print the array from the function Split(). So my question is how to do this ?
This is my code :

```
int main()
{
    string buffer; string delimitor = "::";
    unsigned int param = 0;
    cout << "Please enter how many param: "; cin >> param;
    cout << "Please enter something in the buffer: "; cin >> buffer;
    Split(buffer, delimitor, param);

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

string* Split(string buffer, string delimitor, unsigned int nbr_param)
{
    string* arr = new string[nbr_param];
    unsigned int start = 0, end = buffer.find(delimitor), count = 0;
    while (end != string::npos)
    {
        arr[count] = buffer.substr(start, end - start);
        start = end + delimitor.length();
        end = buffer.find(delimitor, start);
        count++;
    }
    if (end == string::npos)
    {
        arr[count] = buffer.substr(start, end);
    }

    return arr;
}
```

Comment: Better to return `std::vector<std::string>` than raw owning pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store return value in variable, than iterate over it.

```
std::string* words = Split(buffer, delimitor, param);
for (std::size_t i = 0; i != param; ++i) {
    std::cout << words[i] << std::endl;
}
delete[] words;
```

If you return `std::vector<std::string>`, you may do

```
const auto& words = Split(buffer, delimitor); // param is no longer needed.
for (const auto& word : words) {
    std::cout << words[i] << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to use `std::vector`, `push_back` the fragments and do away with the `new` altogether. Probably also just as efficient, as the returned vector would be either moved or constructed in place due to the RVO.

Anyway, you will of course have to assign the return value to a variable in main. Right now you just call split and discard the value, leaking the memory allocated in `Split`.